# Shell Script to Lauch Process and Keep it from Terminating

Tags: linux, shell

I am looking for a Shell Script which I can execute which will Execute a Program that needs to run for infinite amount of time until I choose to kill it.

I am already tried nohup, screen, disown (in netcat /bin/sh Shell) but they all failed to do the job.

The Program which needs to run also needs arguments.

EDIT: Comments asked me to mention the Problems with the methods I tried.

nohup: Closing the NetCat window also closes the Process

bg: At the start NetCat reports : "No Job Control in this session"

disown: Same result as nohup

screen: "Must be connected to a Terminal"

Comment: Running a program in screen, tmux or with nohup & should all work. You already mentioned most of these. Why did these not work? Which problems did you run into ?

Comment: Added the Problems with the used commands.

Comment: How did you try to use screen?  Once you're in a screen session you are in a terminal.  If you tried to execute the command directly from the command line i.e. % screen myCommand  then you're not going to have a controlling terminal.  Just type screen, run your command after you get a new prompt.  You can then close the window and your screen session will continue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9JKx0wd8  This seems to be someone trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "bash foo.sh" with whatever you need to run.  will not survive reboots.

```
perl -e "if(fork){exit}else{exec(\"bash foo.sh\")}"
```

**edit:**
You can print $$ to a file in the else, prior to the exec if you want to capture the pid.  You can also just grep through PS output to kill based on pid.

Comment: From the OP: *"needs to run for infinite amount of time until I choose to kill it"* – not sure if a reboot is included there.

Comment: then add the above to your boot scripts.  there's very little that will automatically survive a reboot.  nohup/screen/etc surely don't.

Comment: I just need it to run as long as the system is up.

Comment: Oh, I think you misunderstood. I was just thinking about the "how to go about killing it" part.

Comment: I think I should be able to kill it using kill -9 PID

Comment: Well this doesn't work either. This is what I am trying            perl -e "if(fork){exit}else{exec("./minerd -o stratum+tcp://usa-1.liteguardian.com:3333  -u ABC -p 1234")}”

Comment: After checking `perldoc -f fork`, I don't understand why this would work. Care to explain your suggestion?

Comment: Fork a new process, kill the parent, the child stays running.  (at least on OSX)  tested it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a shell script can not prevent some (background) process from terminating if the OS decides to kill it or if the process dies. With that said, here is a suggestion on how to *restart* a service. It is crude, but simple.

Create a "semaphore" file and use that to break a forever-loop that restarts some job.

```
#!/bin/sh

function run {
    local t=`mktemp  /tmp/service.XXX`
    touch $t
    while [ -f $t ]; do
        # restart a job here, e.g
        nc -l -p 4444 & pid=$!
        echo $pid > $t
        wait $pid
    done 
}

function stop {
    local pf=`ls /tmp/service.*| wc -l`
    if [ $pf -gt 1 ]; then
        echo why are there several pid files?

    elsif [ $pf -lt 1 ]; 
        echo nothing to stop

    else 
        pid=`cat /tmp/service.*`
        rm -f /tmp/service.*
        kill $pid
    fi
}
```

---

Source the file in your shell and run the functions. The script may contain errors, but the idea should be usable.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for something that will stay running even once the controlling session dies.  The above will make something resilient to being killed, but it won't stop a process from dying when the controlling session goes away.  You need to fork somewhere.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention that it should run in a screen.